# Nested Lists in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get all items that have a data equal to (1 OR 2) AND a data equal to (6 OR 7)

```
var oneFromEachList = new[] {
    new[] {1,2}, // 1 OR 2
    new[] {6,7}, // AND 6 OR 7
};

// item.dataList is an IEnumerable<int>
DbSet<Table>.Where(item => oneFromEachList.All(list => item.dataList.Any(list.Contains)))
```

This query is what I want to do, but it can't be converted to SQL, I get: "The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='Collect'"

Note that the oneFromEachList object is known before the query is executed (it's not from the database). I guess it's possible to build an Expression by composing .Where statements? This seems very complicated for what it is though...

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do, but Dynamic LINQ makes it easy to construct complex Where clauses. https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're going for:

```
var query = DbSet<Table>()
foreach(var list in oneFromEachList)
   query = query.Where(item => item.dataList.Any(list.Contains));
```

You could turn this into a one-liner by using `Aggregate()`:

```
oneFromEachList.Aggregate(DbSet<Table>(), (q, l) => q.Where(item => item.dataList.Any(l.Contains)));
```

But either way you're not going to be able to accomplish what you're looking for without either composing multiple `Where` clauses or doing some manual expression building.